# Qt move widget to cursor position

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop

I am implementing a function (Using Qt) that is supposed to move a widget to the cursor position as part of a drag and drop functionality.

I have three events that get triggered, mouse down, mouse move, and mouse up. When the mouse moves and is down, a signal is sent to the widget to move itself to the cursor; however, I have encountered some strange behavior.

This simple code:

```
void Block::moveToCursor()
{
    block->move(block->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos()));
    qDebug() << block->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos());
}
```

where "block" is a QLabel that is a member of Block and is a child of the window's central widget.

It produces this result:

[image]

As it can be seen in the debug output, the coordinates are flip flopping (or flickering) every time there is a pixel move. The first coordinated are correct but the second set of coordinates seem to be relative to the top right corner of the window.

I have tried all the mapping functions:

```
block->move(block->mapFromParent(QCursor::pos()));
```

-Produces a similar result with the second set of coordinates relative to the center of the window.

```
block->move(block->mapFrom(this->block, QCursor::pos()));
```

-This produces an even stranger result. The block does not flicker and moves correctly with respect to the mouse, but the initial position of the block seems to be off by the distance from the top right corner of the computer screen. It also only shows one point when printed out in debug, yet it is moving on the screen. Every time you see Continue Drag, the mouse has moved at least one pixel.

[image]

Can someone explain this strange behavior to me and show me the correct way of moving the widget to the cursor at the exact position from where it was originally clicked?

Comment: Are you aware that what you're outputting is not what QWidget::move() got called with, as the second mapping (for qDebug() will be based on the already altered position) ? You are correct about mapFromGlobal the QCursor::pos to relative (parent-based) coordinates. I'm not sure right now whether you need to call mapFromGlobal on block->parent()->map..

Comment: What you pointed out doesn't really matter. The only difference is the corrdinates are flipped for the first image. And there is no function that maps coordinates from the block's parent that I can see from the documention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the coordinate in relation to the parent (like wanted from move()-Method), you need to use the mapFromGlobal on the parent like this:

```
block->move(block->parentWidget()->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos()));
```

Just give it a try. The reason for this is, lets consider what happens when you are at position 1,1 inside the child. But the child is for example at position 123,123 from its parent top-left. You would now move it to 1,1, causing it to jump 122 pixels each.

Comment: As I said in my comment, "mapFromGlobal(QPoint)" is not a member of block->parent. So this solution does not work.

Comment: What class does the parent got ?

Comment: I figured it out, block->move(block->parentWidget()->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos()));

Comment: I gave you the answer point because you were pretty close. Just accept my edit or edit it yourself so someone else can use the code.

Comment: Done so. Yea, I was assuming that you'd have to get the widget object. E.g. in a QGraphicsView. Glad you got your stuff working :)